# MVC4 redirect to parent after deleting child item

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a delete action that deletes an item. I want to redirect to an action of the parent of the deleted item after this item is deleted.

```
    // The parent Action
    public ActionResult ParentAction(int id = 0)
    {
        Parent parent = LoadParentFromDB(id);
        return View(parent);
    }

    // Delete action of the child item
    public ActionResult Delete(int id, FormCollection collection)
    {
        DeleteChildFromDB(id);
        return RedirectToParentAction();
    }
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `RedirectToAction` method  and pass the id of the parent object

```
// Delete action of the child item
public ActionResult Delete(int id, FormCollection collection)
{
    var parent_id = queryTheParentObjectId();
    DeleteChildFromDB(id);
    return RedirectToAction("ParentAction", new {id=parent_id})
}
```

You created your own answer and it seems the method you want to call is in another controller.  You don't need to add the controller name as a parameter. You can have this:

```
// instead of doing this
// return RedirectToAction("ParentAction", 
//    new { controller = "ParentController", id = parent_id });
//
// you can do the following
// assuming ParentConroller is the name of your controller
// based on your own answer 
return RedirectToAction("ParentAction", "Parent", new {id=parent_id})
```

Comment: The parent is indeed another controller, the controller param is eliminated as you said and works fine. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @von v.
I've modified your answer a little bit and it works:

```
// Delete action of the child item
public ActionResult Delete(int id, FormCollection collection)
{
    var parent_id = queryTheParentObjectId();
    DeleteChildFromDB(id);
    return RedirectToAction("ParentAction", new { controller = "ParentController", id = parent_id });
}
```

Comment: You don't have to do add the controller parameter, there's an overload for that, see my updated answer.